# How to add item to a list when I only have access to its object?

Tags: c#, generics, generic-list

Somewhere In my application I have a generic list that is created from another assembly using reflection. I only have access to the object of that list. I mean I have an `Object objectOfList` that I know it is a generic list of values(For example int or float values). I need to add items to this list. how can I do that?

As I don't know that what the type of generic list is I tried to cast the `objectOfList` to a list of objects but it throws an exception:

```
(objectOfList as List<object>).Add(value); // value is an integer here
```

It throws null reference exception.

### Update

It could be `int` `float` or any other types. I don't know what the type is when I write the code. This is the user that selects the list type from `UI` and after that the list is created.

Comment: Could it ever be a `List<object>` or will it always be a `List<int>` or `List<float>`? In that case you need to cast based on the type of `value` i.e `((List<int>)objectOfList).Add(value)`;

Comment: @Lee It could be int float or any other type. I don't know what the type is when I write the code. This is the user that selects the list type from `UI` and after that the list is created.

Comment: Yes, but will it always be the exact same type as `value` and not a subtype? In that case you can just cast based on the type of `value`. If the list element type is a supertype of `value` then you can cast to `IList` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As Lee pointed out, you must use the actual type and not `object`. Consider the following:

```
object someList = new List<int>();
(someList as List<object>).Add(1);
```

This will throw a `NullReferenceException` but

```
(someList as List<int>).Add(1);
```

does not.

More information about `as`:

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception

[as (C# reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)

There is one more thing you could try, and that is by losing the generic type safety support of `List<T>` by using the non-generic interface `IList`. This will allow you to do what you want but will throw `System.ArgumentException` if the types are different:

```
(someList as IList).Add(1); //ok
(someList as IList).Add("hello");  //throws exception
```

Answer (score 1):

List is invariant so you can only cast it back to a list with the same element type e.g.

```
int value = 4;
object source = new List<int>();
((List<int>)source).Add(value);
```

If you know that the element type will always match the type of `value`, and you know the type of `value` statically then you can cast.

If you know the list element type could be a supertype of `value` then you can call `IList.Add` instead which is still safe e.g.

```
object source = new List<Animal>();
var g = new Giraffe();
((IList)source).Add(g);
```

note that in this case you cannot cast `source` to a `List<Giraffe>`.

If you don't know that static type of `value` then you will also have to cast to `IList` and be prepared to handle an exception when calling `Add`.

Answer (score 0):

`Object objectOfList` isn't castable to `List<object>` so the `as` operator is returning null.

If you either initialized it as `List<Object> objectOfList` or `Object objectOfList = new List<Object>();` you won't get a null ref. E.g.

```
    Object objectOfList = new List<object>();
    (objectOfList as List<object>).Add(5);
```

([Example fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xaPurU))

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the list of objects back to what it was. if it was a list, then:

> List lo = ((List)objectOfList)

This way you can work with the list.
You can then find out which type of list it is by this method:

> objectOfList.ToString()
>   or
>   objectOfList.GetType().ToString()